# Unable to mount NFS share in Solaris Local zone

Tags: solaris

I am trying to mount one NFS share in my Solaris Local zone.But I am getting error like below.

```
showmount -e hostname
showmount: hostname: RPC: Rpcbind failure - RPC: Timed out.
```

I tried to ping the host but unable to reach.But the same host can be reachable from the global zone.

Comment: Does the zone have network access?  Can it ping the NFS server?

Comment: Yes,it has network access. Buy it is unable to reach the NFS server through ping.at the same time the client server is able to mount another share from a different NFS server.

Comment: Does the NFS server you can't reach respond to pings from other hosts?

Comment: Yes..the NFS server responds to otger servers...

Comment: You might be better off following the instructions at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1460/z.admin.task-11.html for how to correctly add non-gz access to gz filesystems.

Answer (score 1):

For the error `showmount` is giving you, I suspect that error implies that there is no NFS server running on the server you're running the command on.  You note its a Solaris zone, but not which version of Solaris.  You cannot run an NFS server inside a Solaris 10 zone.  You can in one on v11 -- just check Oracle's documentation for the pre-reqs and procedure.